# Группировка и нахождение среднего значения

Tags: c#, linq

```
DataGridViewRow[] dgvr = new DataGridViewRow[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
dataGridView1.Rows.CopyTo(dgvr, 0);

var group = from row in dgvr
    group row by row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() into g
    let avg = g.Average(u => Convert.ToInt32(u.Cells[3].Value))
    select new { Name = g.Key, avg = avg };
```

Пытаюсь сгруппировать и найти среднее значение. Получаю только пустую переменную `group`. Как можно решить ?

[image: Исходные данные]

Comment: Ищите ошибку в другом месте. Например, проверьте что dgvr - не пустой массив...

Comment: Добрый день. Проверял, он не пустой. Может ли быть проблема из-за использования массива класса DataGridViewRow ?

Comment: Нет, не из-за этого. Хотя он все равно лишний.

Comment: Лабораторная в учебных целях. Хочу упростить задачу для себя и за одно попрактиковаться с linq. 
До этого ничего сложного не происходит. Заполнение datagridwiew. После копирование всех строк проходит нормально. Но после linq-запросы получаю пустую переменную

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас второй скриншот. На нем изображено что угодно кроме пустой переменной group.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю. В отладчике, на втором скриншоте должно быть "предоставление результатов" как на первом. Возможно, я дальше что. использую не так ? Сейчас добавлю следующий код в первое сообщение.

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать что там написано.

Comment: Немного изменил использование этой переменной. И, кажется, сейчас будет проще разобраться с проблемой. Сейчас залью скриншот исключения. Происходит, когда пытаюсь вывести информацию Name и avg в Massage сообщение.

Comment: а у Вас точно есть необходимое кол-во *ячеек* в строке?

Comment: Да. Скриншоты мне сайт залить больше 2 не даст. За один шаг до места, где вызывается исключение все идет хорошо. Ячейки есть (их 5) использую вторую по индексу, в которой лежат корректные данные. Но потом вылетает исключение. Может быть нужно использовать эту переменную по-другому ?

Comment: @Bald Во время группировки он проходит по всем 25 индексам, но потом получает откуда-то индекс -1 и именно поэтому выдает исключение. Как можно исправить ?

Comment: можете привести пример исходных данных

Comment: @Bald Перезалил скриншот. Данные лежат в datagridview. После чего я копирую его в массив строк DataGridViewRow[] dgvr.

Comment: Разобрался. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView имеет последнюю строку для добавления данных пользователем. Я просто убрал возможность добавлять данные руками. Либо ее можно было бы просто удалить в исходном массиве.